# Would Brun's constant being transcendental prove the twin prime conjecture?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, twin-primes

Brun's constant $1.9021605831\ldots$ is the sum of the reciprocals of twin primes greater than $2$, that is:
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{19}+\ldots$$

Note $\frac{1}{5}$ is included twice as it's in two pairs of twin primes, but that's not material to this question.

Do I understand correctly, that if this constant were transcendental, that would prove the twin prime conjecture?

Conversely, if there are infinitely many twin primes, this would not necessarily prove that Brun's constant is transcendental.

If we were to assume that there are finitely many twin primes and then use this fact to somehow calculate Brun's constant, might we find that under this supposition Brun's constant must be transcendental and thereby, by contradiction, know that there are infinitely many twin primes?

Comment: By the way, this is not Brun’s Constant. It is actually $1.902160577783278\ldots$ to be more accurate

Comment: @user477343 Seba 2004 I think searched numbers 100 times greater than that estimate and found more twin primes, hence the value went up.

Comment: Yes, that would be true. Also, reading my comment, I sound very.. uhh.. blunt. I didn't mean to sound like I had a frown on my face haha

Comment: And, I stand corrected. Your value of Brun's Constant is actually more accurate... Mine is achieved when $10^{14}$ twin prime pairs are tested and yours is achieved when $10^{16}$ twin prime pairs are tested.

Comment: @user477343 ..which is what I said about him searching numbers 100 times greater. No problem... although it's the first $10^{16}$ integers searched I think rather than first $10^{16}$ twin primes found.

Comment: $\downarrow$ Yes I think you are right there as well. I definitely confirmed it by going over to the site below. http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Primes/twin.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the problem in the contrapositive:  if there are only finitely many pairs of twin primes, then the sum you show has only finitely many terms, and a sum of finitely many rational numbers is rational.  Back in the original direction, if the sum is transcendental, then in particular it is irrational, and in that case the sum can't have only a finite number of terms.  So if Brun's constant is transcendental, then there are infinitely many pairs of twin primes.

But as you say, even if there are infinitely many pairs of twin primes, this (now infinite) series is not guaranteed to converge to a transcendental, or even irrational, number.  There are lots of infinite series that converge to rational numbers.